# Oracle SQLLOADER - How to Load Data in format of dd-mon-rr

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I have text comma separated file in format below.

```
"RAZY","","","","","","","","N","Y","27-JUL-14","1","98727076437","27-JUL-14"
"TEST","","","","","","","","N","Y","27-JUN-14","1","98727076437","27-JUN-79"
```

### I am trying to load this using a SQL loader controlfile.

```
OPTIONS (SKIP=0)
LOAD DATA
INFILE      '/home/test.txt'
BADFILE     '/home/test.bad'
DISCARDFILE '/home/test.dis'
APPEND
INTO TABLE "TEST" 
 fields terminated by ","
optionally enclosed by '"'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
( 
  NAME                  ,
  TITLE                 ,
  INITIAL               ,
  SURNAME               ,
  STREET        ,
  TOWN          ,
  COUNTY        ,
  POSTCODE              ,
  TELEPHONE             ,
  FLAG        ,
  Update_DATE        DATE  "TO_DATE(:Update_DATE,'DD-MON-RR')",
  Update_STATUS      ,
  VISIT_REFERENCE  ,
  LOADED_DATE           DATE  "TO_DATE(:LOADED_DATE,'DD-MON-RR')"
 )
```

---

But returned an error "ORA-01821: date format not recognized"

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
  Update_DATE        DATE  "DD-MON-RR",
  LOADED_DATE        DATE  "DD-MON-RR"
```